# CI/CD Gitlab deployment Failed - dbl command not found

Tags: heroku, continuous-integration, pipeline, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

The pipeline **.gitlab-ci.yml** code successfully works till yesterday, but today i got the error which says “dpl command not found”

the below is my **.gitlab-ci.yml** file

```
image: node:8.9.3

stages:
  - job1
  - test
  - production

job1:
  stage: job1
  script: "ls -l"

test:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - npm install

production:
  type: deploy
  stage: production
  image: ruby:latest
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=quailapp --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
  only:
    - master
```

This is the log Generated,

```
Setting up rake (10.5.0-2) ...
Setting up libruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.3-1+deb9u2) ...
Setting up ruby2.3 (2.3.3-1+deb9u2) ...
Setting up ruby2.3-dev:amd64 (2.3.3-1+deb9u2) ...
Setting up ruby-dev:amd64 (1:2.3.3) ...
Setting up ruby (1:2.3.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
$ gem install dpl
Successfully installed dpl-1.9.6
1 gem installed
$ dpl --provider=heroku --app=quailapp --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
/bin/bash: line 68: dpl: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

please help me for finding the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Same here, Issuing the command to install dpl with verbosity: `gem install dpl --verbose` I've been able to see something weird:

```
/usr/local/bundle/bin/dpl
Successfully installed dpl-1.9.6
1 gem installed
```

I don't know why but it is installed in a non-default path. As a workaround I've added the `/usr/local/bundle/bin` in `$PATH` environment variable issuing the following command:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bundle/bin`

It works for me and my gitlab ci pipelines are now working again.

BTW, It would be great to know why it has changed suddenly...

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here. I think, it's a problem in docker image. See https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/pull/209

They made some changes and broke path for gems binaries. We have to wait until they merge fix.

**UPDATE**:

It's already merged and their fix works for me.

Comment: Here it goes the WHY... Thank you for posting it out!